# Relation between rank of matrix and eigenvalues.

Tags: matrix-rank

Suppose matrix $A$ has rank $k$. If all the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are real, then is it true that $A^TA$ has $k$ positive eigenvalues(including repeated ones)? Can this be addressed using rank nullity theorem? Appreciate if one could advise me on that. Thank you.

Comment: $A^TA$ is symmetric. If all of its entries are real, then so are all of its eigenvalues.

Comment: Does it mean that $k$ of the eigenvalues are positive?